# Python script fails after 2 iterations

Tags: python, matplotlib, iteration, visualization

I wrote a script that takes a specified octahedron and refines it. For context, I have pictures of the output with `iterations` set to `0`,`1`, and `2`.

[image: iteration0] [image: iteration1] [image: iteration2]

When I set `iterations=3`, however, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amaurydeburgos/Documents/WinterBreak2023.py", line 78, in <module>
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([ [ Vertices[i] for i in f] for f in Faces],edgecolors='k',facecolors='w'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 701, in __init__
    super().__init__(verts, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 454, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 1176, in __init__
    self.set_verts(verts, closed)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 745, in set_verts
    self.get_vector(verts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 734, in get_vector
    xs, ys, zs = np.row_stack(segments3d).T
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in vstack
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 296, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0, dtype=dtype, casting=casting)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 3 and the array at index 689 has size 0
```

I don't know what's going wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated. The script I wrote is below:

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from numpy.linalg import norm
from operator import add
from itertools import combinations
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

# Initial octahedron

Vertices = [ (0,0,1), (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (-1,0,0), (0,-1,0), (0,0,-1) ]
Edges = { frozenset({0,1}), frozenset({0,2}), frozenset({0,3}), frozenset({0,4}),
          frozenset({1,2}), frozenset({2,3}), frozenset({3,4}), frozenset({1,4}),
          frozenset({1,5}), frozenset({2,5}), frozenset({3,5}), frozenset({4,5}) }
Faces = { frozenset({0,1,2}), frozenset({0,2,3}), frozenset({0,3,4}), frozenset({0,1,4}),
          frozenset({1,2,5}), frozenset({2,3,5}), frozenset({3,4,5}), frozenset({1,4,5}) }

iterations = 3

for i in range(iterations):

    # Initializing set of new vertices, new edges, and new faces

    counter = len(Vertices)-1

    newVertices = []
    newEdges = set()
    newFaces = set()    

    # Adding elements of newVertices and trivial elements of newEdges

    for edge in Edges:
        counter = counter+1
        newVertex = np.array([0,0,0])
        for vertex in edge:
            newVertex = np.add(newVertex,np.array(Vertices[vertex]))
        
            newEdge = frozenset({vertex,counter})
            newEdges.add(newEdge)
        newVertex = np.divide(newVertex,norm(newVertex,2))
        newVertices.append(tuple(newVertex))

    # Adding non-trivial elements of newEdges and elements of newFaces

    for face in Faces:
        middleFace=set()
        SpecialEdges=set()
        pairsOfSpecialEdges={(a,b) for a,b in combinations({edge for edge in newEdges if len(edge.intersection(face))==1},2) if (a & b) and len((a-face).intersection(b-face))==1}
        for pair in pairsOfSpecialEdges:
            for edge in pair:
                SpecialEdges.add(edge)
        for vertex in face:
            incidentEdges={edge for edge in SpecialEdges if vertex in edge}
            newEdge=set()
            for edge in incidentEdges:
                for v in edge:
                    if v==vertex:
                        continue
                    else:
                        newEdge.add(v)
                        middleFace.add(v)
            newEdges.add(frozenset(newEdge))
            newEdge.add(vertex)
            newFaces.add(frozenset(newEdge))
            newFaces.add(frozenset(middleFace))
        
    Vertices = Vertices+newVertices
    Edges.clear()
    Edges.update(newEdges)
    Faces.clear()
    Faces.update(newFaces)

### Plotting ###

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set(xlim=(-1,1), ylim=(-1,1), zlim=(-1,1))
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([ [ Vertices[i] for i in f] for f in Faces],edgecolors='k',facecolors='w'))
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I have provided a fix in my answer, don't know much about what the different iterations should look like but let me know if it is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem to be on line 59,  Please see my inline comments and images below:

```
        for vertex in face:
            incidentEdges = {edge for edge in SpecialEdges if vertex in edge}
            newEdge = set() # this wasn't checked if incidentEdges was empty
            for edge in incidentEdges:
                for v in edge:
                    if v == vertex:
                        continue
                    else:
                        newEdge.add(v)
                        middleFace.add(v)
            if not newEdge: continue # added this to prevent an empty frozenset being added later on
            newEdges.add(frozenset(newEdge)) # this was adding the empty edge
            newEdge.add(vertex)
            newFaces.add(frozenset(newEdge)) # this was creating an empty frozen set which causes it to fail later
            newFaces.add(frozenset(middleFace))
```

My change produces this for iteration 3 and 4.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So I had a look, I belive that something in your loop may be creating polygons of smaller number of vertices (hadn't looked too deep to be honest to identify where/how it happens).

Poly3DCollection must be complaining that it cannot create a polygon without edges.

Hopefully this should be enough to point you in the right direction. The application is very nice if you manage to fix it would love to see it fully functional, best of luck! :)

```py
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from numpy.linalg import norm
from operator import add
from itertools import combinations
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

# Initial octahedron

Vertices = [ (0,0,1), (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (-1,0,0), (0,-1,0), (0,0,-1) ]
Edges = { frozenset({0,1}), frozenset({0,2}), frozenset({0,3}), frozenset({0,4}),
          frozenset({1,2}), frozenset({2,3}), frozenset({3,4}), frozenset({1,4}),
          frozenset({1,5}), frozenset({2,5}), frozenset({3,5}), frozenset({4,5}) }
Faces = { frozenset({0,1,2}), frozenset({0,2,3}), frozenset({0,3,4}), frozenset({0,1,4}),
          frozenset({1,2,5}), frozenset({2,3,5}), frozenset({3,4,5}), frozenset({1,4,5}) }

for iterations in range(0,3):
# iterations = 3

    for i in range(iterations):
    
        # Initializing set of new vertices, new edges, and new faces
        counter = len(Vertices)-1
    
        newVertices = []
        newEdges = set()
        newFaces = set()    
    
        # Adding elements of newVertices and trivial elements of newEdges
        for edge in Edges:
            counter = counter+1
            newVertex = np.array([0,0,0])
            for vertex in edge:
                newVertex = np.add(newVertex,np.array(Vertices[vertex]))
            
                newEdge = frozenset({vertex,counter})
                newEdges.add(newEdge)
            newVertex = np.divide(newVertex,norm(newVertex,2))
            newVertices.append(tuple(newVertex))
    
        # Adding non-trivial elements of newEdges and elements of newFaces
        for face in Faces:
            middleFace=set()
            SpecialEdges=set()
            pairsOfSpecialEdges={(a,b) for a,b in combinations({edge for edge in newEdges if len(edge.intersection(face))==1},2) if (a & b) and len((a-face).intersection(b-face))==1}
            for pair in pairsOfSpecialEdges:
                for edge in pair:
                    SpecialEdges.add(edge)
            for vertex in face:
                incidentEdges={edge for edge in SpecialEdges if vertex in edge}
                newEdge=set()
                for edge in incidentEdges:
                    for v in edge:
                        if v==vertex:
                            continue
                        else:
                            newEdge.add(v)
                            middleFace.add(v)
                newEdges.add(frozenset(newEdge))
                newEdge.add(vertex)
                newFaces.add(frozenset(newEdge))
                newFaces.add(frozenset(middleFace))
            
        Vertices = Vertices+newVertices
        Edges.clear()
        Edges.update(newEdges)
        Faces.clear()
        Faces.update(newFaces)
    
    ### Plotting ###
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.set(xlim=(-1,1), ylim=(-1,1), zlim=(-1,1))
    col =[ [ Vertices[i] for i in f] for f in Faces]
    n_vertices_per_polygon=[len(x) for x in col]
    print(f"Iteration {iterations}: Polygon with least number of vertices has {min(n_vertices_per_polygon)} vertices")
    print("Vertices on polygons:", n_vertices_per_polygon)

    col3d=Poly3DCollection(col,edgecolors='k',facecolors='w')
    ax.add_collection3d(col3d)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]